# How can i color specific item on ContextMenu when doing right click with the mouse?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is an event of dataGridView1 mouse click when i click right mouse it open a contextmenu.
In this case with 4 items. 
I want that the last item will be colored with Red.
I can disable the last item but i want now to color it.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
                m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Cut"));
                m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Copy"));
                m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Paste"));

                int currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

                if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
                {
                    m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(string.Format("Row number {0}", currentMouseOverRow.ToString())));
                    m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].OwnerDraw = true;
                    m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].DrawItem += Cm_DrawItem;
                    //m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count -1].Enabled = false;
                }

                m.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            }
        }
```

This is the Cm_DrawItem event:

```
void Cm_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (MenuItem)sender;
            var g = e.Graphics;
            var font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Italic);
            var brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
            g.DrawString(item.Text, font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
        }
```

I used a breakpoint and it's getting to the Cm_DrawItem event but it didn't color it. More then that when using this Cm_DrawItem event i see now only 3 items.

EDIT

This is what i get now after change the code according to the solutions:

[image]

This is the code now:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
                m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Cut"));
                m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Copy"));
                m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Paste"));

                int currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

                if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
                {
                    m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].OwnerDraw = true;
                    m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].DrawItem += Cm_DrawItem;
                    m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(string.Format("Row number {0}", currentMouseOverRow.ToString())));

                    //m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count -1].Enabled = false;
                }

                m.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            }
        }
```

And the event:

```
void Cm_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (MenuItem)sender;
            var g = e.Graphics;
            var font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Italic);
            var brush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            g.DrawString(item.Text, font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
        }
```

But i want it to color the whole line this line:

```
m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(string.Format("Row number {0}", currentMouseOverRow.ToString())));
```

For example if i did right mouse click on row 5 so the text: Row number 5 should be at Red color including the number.

But as you see in the screenshot it's coloring something else.

EDIT

I also saw now that the code in the mouse click event should be as before:

```
m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(string.Format("Row number {0}", currentMouseOverRow.ToString())));
m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].OwnerDraw = true;
m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].DrawItem += Cm_DrawItem;
```

If i will change it as in the first solution then the text that will be passed for coloring will be Paste since i didnt add yet the Ro number line...

And stil it dosent color the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to measure the item size for your owner drawn item in context menu (don't know if this is a bug or intentional - didn't find any documentation on this).

Try this:

```
if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
{
    m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(string.Format("Row number {0}", currentMouseOverRow.ToString())));
    m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].OwnerDraw = true;
    m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].DrawItem += Cm_DrawItem;
    m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].MeasureItem += MeasureMenuItem;
}

void MeasureMenuItem(object sender,MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem m = (MenuItem) sender;
    Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, Font.Size, Font.Style);
    SizeF sze = e.Graphics.MeasureString(m.Text, font);
    e.ItemHeight = (int)sze.Height;
    e.ItemWidth = (int)sze.Width;
}
```

Currently your menu item will be drawn in the default color. if you want to change the color you should do it in `Cm_DrawItem` as per @C-Pound's solution.

```
var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red); //or whatever color you want.
```

Note: the owner drawn item means you have to fully draw the item, means you have to offset the drawing for the image on the left side.

*Edit:* Additional notes
You can also change the size of the menu item in the measure item, usually +4 for height and width looks nice,

```
e.ItemHeight = (int)sze.Height+4;
e.ItemWidth = (int)sze.Width+4;
```

In the Drawing routine an offset of +16 makes the menu item aligned to the other items.

```
g.DrawString(item.Text, font, brush, e.Bounds.X+16, e.Bounds.Y);
```

Comment: bansi i changed the code according to your solution and also added the brush line with the red color but it's not working good. Please look at my question i added the code im using now and also a screenshot of what im getting now.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right from the starting.
just need to add this event handler for the menu item

```
m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].MeasureItem += menuItem2_MeasureItem;
```

and define corresponding event handler:

```
private void menuItem2_MeasureItem(object sender,System.Windows.Forms.MeasureItemEventArgs e)
        {
            e.ItemWidth = 75;
            e.ItemHeight = 18;
        }
```

It will fix your problem.  I was in the same situation as yours and it worked for me.
For more detail: reference

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/owner-draw-menus-in-C-Sharp/

Best regards,
Himanshu